# Lost precision on GMP mpf_add. Where have my digits gone?

Tags: c, precision, gmp

I'm summing two negative floats:

```
char * lhs = "-2234.6016114467412141";
char * rhs = "-4939600281397002.2812";
```

According to Perl, using bignum and Math::BigFloat, the answer is

```
-4939600281399236.8828114467412141
```

However, according to GMP, using the code below, the answer is

```
-4939600281399236.88281
```

Where have I gone wrong? What happened to the remaining "14467412141"?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "gmp-static\gmp.h"
#include <stdlib.h>         /* For _MAX_PATH definition */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <math.h>

#define F(x) mpf_t x; mpf_init( x );

void main(void)
{
    F(f_lhs);
    F(f_rhs);
    F(f_res);

    char * resbuff;

    mp_exp_t exp;

    char * lhs = "-2234.6016114467412141";
    char * rhs = "-4939600281397002.2812";

    int validOp = mpf_set_str( f_lhs, lhs, 10 );
    validOp = mpf_set_str( f_rhs, rhs, 10 );

    mpf_add( f_res, f_lhs, f_rhs );

    resbuff = mpf_get_str( NULL, &exp, 10, 0, f_res );
    printf( "Using mpf_add, %s + %s = %s (exp=%d)\n", lhs, rhs, resbuff, exp );

    free(resbuff);
}
```

Sample output:

```
Using mpf_add, -2234.6016114467412141 + -4939600281397002.2812 = -493960028139923688281 (exp=16)
```

*P.S.* I have tried adding a call to `mpf_set_default_prec` with larger than 64 (the default) values, but to no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are overflowing the mantissa at 64 bits.  Try doing `mpf_get_prec(f_res)` to check it is the precision you want.  If not call the `mpf_set_default_prec()` before you initialize any mpf vars (line 1 of main).

Comment: Spot on. I changed my macro to 
  #define F(x) mpf_t (x); mpf_init2( (x), 128L ); 
and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Boot with a larger value. Try this:

```
mpf_set_default_prec(5*1024)
```